# Obtener todos los select de un div

Tags: html, c#

De una pagina intento tomar distintos div el primero contiene input y si los trae todos pero el segundo div contiene select que igual quiero mostrar pero solo me muestra el primero

```cs
 private void BuscarHtml()
        {
            var url = "http://...";
            var web = new HtmlWeb();
            var doc = web.Load(url);

            var node = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@class='aspNetHidden']//input | //div[@class='center-block']//select");
            foreach (var item in node)
            {
                var resultado = item.OuterHtml + "En total hay: " + node.Count;
                txtSource.Text += resultado + "\n";
            }
        }
```

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español! Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! y si en lugar de hacer el selectNodes asi, lo haces por separado si anda? tal vez solo este mal la cadena de seleccion ;)